# Subset DataFrame Based on Quantile from Describe()

Tags: python, dataframe

How do I subset a list of dataframe based on whether or not a columns value exceeds a value in the quantile?

For example, how do I subset df.Identifiers where the `50% quantile > 0`?

The remaining `df.Identifier` would include `abc1, abc6, and abc83`.

OR

how do I obtain a list of `Identifier` where the `50% quantile > 0`?

The list would include [`abc1, abc6, abc83`].

```
count   mean    std min 25% 50% 75% max
Indentifier                             
abc1    739.0   328.847307  231.728459  -3.854524e-05   151.235850  362.193201  466.095210  1283.288224
abc6    739.0   468.393177  294.507741  -8.394400e-01   302.310773  398.086193  570.334380  1738.466313
abc83   739.0   337.178163  246.586688  0.000000e+00    136.026517  288.938625  525.148871  974.147424
abc45   715.0   105.984895  212.980208  0.000000e+00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1166.600000
abc4    691.0   104.105644  271.766773  0.000000e+00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1105.000000
abc55   691.0   96.467438   261.348898  0.000000e+00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1220.000000
abc56   712.0   89.839888   241.175607  0.000000e+00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    996.000000
abc7    711.0   85.864979   234.952159  0.000000e+00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1024.0000
```

Comment: Are you showing your expected or input dataframe?

Comment: this is .describe() output..

Comment: it would be more helpful if you showed your input df and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what are your criteria of choosing mentioned "subset", but if you want to measure it by e.g. rolling window, you can use `.expanding()` (for open ended), or `rolling(n)` for rolling window of `n` observations.

For instance:

```py
df["y_expanding_quantile"]=df["y"].expanding().quantile(0.3)
df["y_rolling_quantile"]=df["y"].rolling(3, min_periods=1, center=False).quantile(0.33)
```

Example with dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"x": list("ppppqqqr"), "y": [3,2,1,-5,-1,-2,7,0]})

df["y_expanding_quantile"]=df["y"].expanding().quantile(0.3)
df["y_rolling_quantile"]=df["y"].rolling(3, min_periods=1, center=False).quantile(0.33)

print(df)
```

Outputs:

```py
   x  y  y_expanding_quantile  y_rolling_quantile
0  p  3                   3.0                3.00
1  p  2                   2.3                2.33
2  p  1                   1.6                1.66
3  p -5                   0.4               -1.04
4  q -1                  -0.6               -2.36
5  q -2                  -1.5               -3.02
6  q  7                  -1.2               -1.34
7  r  0                  -0.9               -0.68
```

Then to filter your data - you can use for instance:

```py
df=df.loc[df["y_rolling_quantile"]>0]
```